# Custom properties that can be used by all properties in OpenFire

Tags: openfire

Can I set a custom property in OpenFire that can be read by other plugins?

I need to set a global property in one OF plugin and have the other plugins pick it up.  it will be a simple string.

I just couldn't find that in the docs

After MrPk's advice, I found the correct spot in JiveGlobals.  There is a set and get property.

```
/**
 * Sets a Jive property. If the property doesn't already exists, a new
 * one will be created.
 *
 * @param name the name of the property being set.
 * @param value the value of the property being set.
 */
public static void setProperty(String name, String value) {
    setProperty(name, value, false);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store your property  in **`OFPROPERTY`** table (or by **admin console -> System Properties**).

As example, `shared.const.test` -> `myValueFoo`

Then, programmatically, you can retrieve it by invoking something like

```
String propertyValue = JiveGlobals.getProperty("shared.const.test", "myValueDefaultIfNotFound");
```

So **`propertyValue`** will be "*myValueDefaultIfNotFound*" if select from db is null, "*myValueFoo*" if you had all right.

Comment: Thanks, I am assuming I can set a property this way as well?  Such as JiveGlobals.setProperty("shared.const.test", "myValue");

Comment: As i know yes BUT you risk to have it only in session. So I suggest you to pass by database, directly with an insert or indirectly by Admin Console